# $f(x)=\frac{10x}{x^2+1}$ Find greatest value of $\delta$ accurate to three decimal places that $0<|x-1|<\delta$ guaruntee $|f(x)-5|<0.01$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

$f(x)=\frac{10x}{x^2+1}$ Find greatest value of $\delta$ accurate to three decimal places that $0<|x-1|<\delta$ guaruntee $|f(x)-5|<0.01$

My question- How do I even start?!

Comment: Start with $|\frac {10x}{x^2+1}-5|<.01$ and conclude that means $j <x -1 < k $ for some j and k...

Comment: You don't know how to start. Okay here is what I would do. 1.Find a piece of paper. 2.Sketch a graph of the function $f(x)$. 3.On the y-axis mark the upper and lower bounds, i.e. $5.01$ and $4.99$. 4.Find the intersection of these bounds with the function $f$. 5.Read the corresponding $x$ values.